# I need to get rid of something I did on the powersave!

Tags: pokemon-super-mystery-dungeon

I have Pokemon Super Mystery Dungeon and I used the powersave to get Darkrai and Giratina. I thought it would just give me the Pokemon, but it restarted me with them. How do I get my old save back? Because I don't want to restart the game.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't back up your save?

Comment: I guess so. But I just got it and don't know how to back up my save.

Comment: I don't think you can. You should always back up your save files before editing them.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the code set you and your partner to physically be Darkrai and Giratina.

If you did not back up your save beforehand (which is the primary purpose of powersaves), the only way you can reverse this while keeping your save data intact is to try using codes to set you and your partner to the original pokémon they were.

If you can't do this, your only other option is to restart the game.